# Dados incorretos sendo inseridos no list Widget

Tags: mysql, python

depois de muito tentar, consegui fazer com que meu programa que é um simulador de caixa (automação comercial) a possibilidade de multiplicar os itens (ao invés do caixa registrar um a um, quando é do mesmo produto). Só que tem um erro, ele insere dados demais conforme mostra a figura.

Existem duas formas de entradas do usuário, com código puro para registro de um único item ou caso ele precise multiplicar é necessário fazer, por exemplo, 10 * 1 (onde 10 é a quantidade a ser multiplicada e 1 o código do produto Dipirona). Conforme mostra a figura, ele reconhece também 10 * 1 (como sendo 10 o código do produto Diovan e 1 o fator de multiplicação).

No exemplo da figura, ele tá registrando os dois tanto 10 * 1 como 10 sendo quantidade a ser multiplicada, quanto 10 como sendo código. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Não estou conseguindo solucionar.

OBS: Eu sempre coloco um saudação, "olá amigos" no início das minhas perguntas, mas elas não saem na mensagem, não sei porque.

---

O código

---

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", database="db_farmacia", password="")
cursor = mydb.cursor()

def funcao_1():    # função/método responsável por buscar código correspondente no banco de dados e retornar dados na tela
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    codigo = pdv.inserir_codigo.text()
    entrada = codigo.strip().split('*')
    pdv.inserir_codigo.setText(" ")
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT nome_produto, preço from tb_produtos WHERE codigo = '{entrada[0]}';")
    for item in cursor.fetchall():
        descricao = item[0]
        preco = item[1]
        quantidade = 1
        pdv.label_descricao.setText(f'  {descricao}')  # label da descrição
        pdv.label_preco_unit.setText(f'  {preco}')  # label do valor unitário
        pdv.label_quantidade.setText(f' {quantidade}')  # label da quantidade
        pdv.label_total.setText(f'{preco}')  # label total = valor unitário x quantidade

        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO tb_registrados(produto, preco, quantidade, total) Values('{descricao}', '{preco}', '{quantidade}', '{preco}');")
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_registrados;")

        for p in cursor.fetchall():
            pdv.label_subtotal.setText(f"{p[0]:>7.2f}")  # label do subtotal

        contador = pdv.listWidget_2.count()  # contando quantos itens aparecem na lista (listWidget)
        contador = contador + 1
        pdv.listWidget_2.insertItem(1000, f" {contador:0>3}...{codigo}... {descricao} \n {quantidade} x {preco:.>10.2f}...............R${preco:>7.2f}")


    if '*' in codigo:
        entrada = codigo.strip().split('*')
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT nome_produto, preço from tb_produtos WHERE codigo = '{entrada[1]}';")
        for item in cursor.fetchall():
            print(entrada)
            descricao = item[0]
            preco = item[1]
            quantidade = int(entrada[0])
            total = preco * quantidade

            pdv.label_descricao.setText(f'  {descricao}')  # label da descrição
            pdv.label_preco_unit.setText(f'  {preco}')  # label do valor unitário
            pdv.label_quantidade.setText(f' {quantidade}')  # label da quantidade
            pdv.label_total.setText(f'{total:>7.2f}') # label total = valor unitário x quantidade

        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO tb_registrados(produto, preco, quantidade, total) Values('{descricao}', '{preco}', '{quantidade}', '{total}');")
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_registrados;")

        for p in cursor.fetchall():
            pdv.label_subtotal.setText(f"{p[0]:>7.2f}")  # label do subtotal

        contador = pdv.listWidget_2.count()  # contando quantos itens aparecem na lista (listWidget)
        contador = contador + 1
        pdv.listWidget_2.insertItem(1000, f" {contador:0>3}...{codigo.split('*')[1]}... {descricao} \n {quantidade} x {preco:.>10.2f}...............R${total:>7.2f}")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido depois que mudei o código para a seguinte forma/sintaxe:

```
def funcao_1():    # função/método responsável por buscar código correspondente no banco de dados e retornar dados na tela
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    codigo = pdv.inserir_codigo.text()
    pdv.inserir_codigo.clear()
    if '*' in codigo:
        entrada = codigo.strip().split('*')
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT nome_produto, preço from tb_produtos WHERE codigo = '{entrada[1]}';")
        for item in cursor.fetchall():
            print(entrada)
            descricao = item[0]
            preco = item[1]
            quantidade = int(entrada[0])
            total = preco * quantidade

            pdv.label_descricao.setText(f'  {descricao}')  # label da descrição
            pdv.label_preco_unit.setText(f'  {preco}')  # label do valor unitário
            pdv.label_quantidade.setText(f' {quantidade}')  # label da quantidade
            pdv.label_total.setText(f'{total:>7.2f}')  # label total = valor unitário x quantidade

            cursor.execute(
                f"INSERT INTO tb_registrados(produto, preco, quantidade, total) Values('{descricao}', '{preco}', '{quantidade}', '{total}');")

            cursor.execute(f"SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_registrados;")
            for p in cursor.fetchall():
                print(p)
                pdv.label_subtotal.setText(f"{p[0]:>7.2f}")

            contador = pdv.listWidget_2.count()  # contando quantos itens aparecem na lista (listWidget)
            contador = contador + 1
            pdv.listWidget_2.insertItem(1000, f" {contador:0>3}...{codigo.split('*')[0]}... {descricao} \n {quantidade} x {preco:.>10.2f}...............R${total:>7.2f}")


    else:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT nome_produto, preço from tb_produtos WHERE codigo = '{codigo}';")
        for item in cursor.fetchall():
            descricao = item[0]
            preco = item[1]
            quantidade = 1


            pdv.label_descricao.setText(f'  {descricao}')  # label da descrição
            pdv.label_preco_unit.setText(f'  {preco}')  # label do valor unitário
            pdv.label_quantidade.setText(f' {quantidade}')  # label da quantidade
            pdv.label_total.setText(f'{preco:>7.2f}')  # label total = valor unitário x quantidade

            cursor.execute(
                f"INSERT INTO tb_registrados(produto, preco, quantidade, total) Values('{descricao}', '{preco}', '{quantidade}', '{preco}');")

            cursor.execute(f"SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_registrados;")
            for p in cursor.fetchall():
                print(p)
                pdv.label_subtotal.setText(f"{p[0]:>7.2f}")

            contador = pdv.listWidget_2.count()  # contando quantos itens aparecem na lista (listWidget)
            contador = contador + 1
            pdv.listWidget_2.insertItem(1000, f" {contador:0>3}...{codigo}... {descricao} \n 1 x {preco:.>10.2f}...............R${preco:>7.2f}")
```